# Sum in C, from two numbers

Tags: c

Im creating a simple program in C that user insert a number, for example 5 and the program sums until 5, 0+1+2+3+4. Im using this formula

```
int sum_naturals(int n){
    return (n-1)*n/2;
}
```

But now i want a formula that can sum from 2 different numbers, like user inserts number 5 and 9 and the program will do 5+6+7+8+9.

Can someone have ideia how can resolve this? Thanks

Comment: You can't use a for loop?

Comment: @bpgeck a loop for this would be fine if your input was `5`, but what if your input is `56789012`? Would you still prefer a loop, or an O(1) operation?

Comment: @bpgeck no just a function or change that already written

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can reuse your function

```
int sum(int a, int b) {
  return sum_naturals(b) - sum_naturals(a-1)
}
```

Of course you have to add some validation.

Comment: If you try with 5 and 9 the result will be 30 when the right 5+6+7+8+9=35

Comment: You are right. I assumed that 'sum_natural' sums values from 0 to n inclusive.

Comment: So the body of proper function should be: `return sum_naturals(b+1) - sum_naturals(a);`

Answer (score 4):

Why not this?

```
 int sum_2_naturals(int n, int m){
    return (sum_naturals(m) - sum_naturals(n))
}
```

Answer (score 3):

> But now i want a formula that can sum from 2 different numbers,

To find the sum of a certain number of terms of an arithmetic sequence:

```
#include <stdio.h>

static int sum_naturals(int a, int b)
{
    return ((b - a + 1) * (a + b)) / 2;
}

int main(void)
{
    printf("%d\n", sum_naturals(5, 9));
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
35
```

[More info](http://www.regentsprep.org/regents/math/algtrig/atp2/arithseq.htm)

Comment: This is a good formula but i neet to use two sum_naturals to get the result :/

Comment: @user5364197 it looks like you've got your answer then in one of the others, and this one is an honerable mention. Please be sure to "accept" (click the check mark) next to whichever answer you feel helped you (and if more than one did, check one and be sure to "up vote" other valuable contributions).

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a simple task, but since you still have problems understanding it, why don't you 'define' your functions first - before 'coding' them.

*S*(*n*) = 0 + 1 + 2 + ... + *n*-1 = *n*(*n*-1)/2

*F*(*k*,*n*) = *k* + *k*+1 + ... + *n*-1 + *n* = -(0 + 1 + ... + *k*-1) + (0 + 1 + ... + *k*-1) + *k* + *k*+1 + ... + *n*-1 + *n* = -*S*(*k*) + *S*(*n*) + *n* = *S*(*n*+1) - *S*(*k*)

Of course, need to assume that k <= n etc.

I guess the reason of all confusion is that you defined your basic function to sum from 0 to *n*-1, instead of 1 to *n*.